# How to find the MLE of a uniform distribution?

Tags: r, mle, uniform-distribution

I am trying to find the maximum likelihood estimators a_hat and b_hat for a given uniform distribution X ~ UNIF(1,3) using R. Below is my code and its output:

```
##Example: Uniform Distribution
x<-runif(100,1,3)
n<-length(x)
ll<-function(a,b){

  -sum(1/(b-a)^n,log=TRUE)

}
m0<-mle2(ll,start=list(a=1,b=2))
summary(m0)

> summary(m0)
```

Maximum likelihood estimation

```
Call:
mle2(minuslogl = ll, start = list(a = 1, b = 2))

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(z)
a   1.5159         NA      NA    NA
b   1.4841         NA      NA    NA

-2 log L: -1.542595e+150 
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object@vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

I am not able to reason why my coefficients are so off from the original values. I am pretty much sure I am using the correct likelihood function for uniform distribution, but I may be wrong for it as well syntax somewhere. I am using `library(bbmle)`

Comment: Hi, I don't know the `bbmle::mle2` function, but don't you have to feed `x` to it somewhere ?

Comment: Hi @Florian. Thanks for your comment. You are correct that we need to inject x in the function, but since its a uniform distribution, we already know that the density will be independent of x. Hence I directly used what I knew would be the density. 

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone who helped.

1. I contacted my professor and it turned out I can't use the "bbmle" for distributions which are not differentiable.
2. In this case log(constant=1/b-a) is not differentiable to get a maxima.
3. There is another R package called "**ExtDist**" which output MLE very well for all distributions (so far for me, including uniform) but doesn't provide standard error of them, which infact "bbmle" does

Just to help anyone who may stumble upon this post in future:

Normal, "bbmle":

```
#Comparison of mentioned packages
  #Example for normal distribution
  set.seed(123)
  library("bbmle")
  x<-rnorm(100,1,3) #mean=1, sd = 3
  n<-length(x)
  ll<-function(a,b){
    -sum(dnorm(x,a,b,log=TRUE)) 
  }
  m0<-mle2(ll,start=list(a=1,b=2))
  summary(m0)
```

Results:

```
Maximum likelihood estimation

 Call:
 mle2(minuslogl = ll, start = list(a = 1, b = 2))

 Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
 a  1.27122    0.27247  4.6655 3.079e-06 ***
 b  2.72473    0.19267 14.1421 < 2.2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 -2 log L: 484.2609
```

Normal, "ExtDist":

```
library("ExtDist")
  m1<-eNormal(X=x,method = "unbiased.MLE")
  m1
```

Results:

```
 Parameters for the Normal distribution. 
 (found using the  unbiased.MLE method.)

  Parameter     Type Estimate      S.E.
       mean location 1.271218 0.2738448
         sd    scale 2.738448 0.1946130
```

Uniform , "bbmle":

```
#Example for uniform distribution
  set.seed(123)
  x<-runif(100,1,3) #minimum =1, maximum = 3
  range(x)  #To know beforehand the original minimum and maximum before the      package estimates
 [1] 1.00125 2.98854
  n<-length(x)
  ll<-function(a,b){ 
    -sum(dunif(x,a,b,log=TRUE))   
  }
 m3<-mle2(ll,start=list(a=1,b=2))
 Error in optim(par = c(1, 2), fn = function (p)  : 
   initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
  summary(m3)
```

Error message:

```
 Error in optim(par = c(1, 2), fn = function (p)  : 
 initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Uniform, "ExtDist":

```
 m4<-eUniform(X=x,method = "unbiased.MLE")
  m4

 Parameters for the Uniform distribution. 
 (found using the  numerical.MLE method.)

  Parameter     Type Estimate
          a boundary 1.001245
          b boundary 2.988544
```

Answer (score 1):

The negative log-likelihood is `-n*log(1/(b-a))=n*log(b-a)` if `a<min(x)` and `b>max(x)`. If these constraints are not satisfied then the likelihood is `0`.

You can specifiy the constraints with `method = "L-BFGS-B"`:

```
library(bbmle)
x <- runif(100,1,3)
n <- length(x)
ll <- function(a,b){
  n*log(b-a)
}

m0 <- mle2(ll, start=list(a=0, b=4), 
           lower=c(a=-Inf, b=max(x)), upper=c(a=min(x), b=Inf), 
           method="L-BFGS-B")
```

You get:

```
Warning message:
In mle2(ll, start = list(a = 0, b = 4), lower = c(a = -Inf, b = max(x)),  :
  some parameters are on the boundary: variance-covariance calculations based on Hessian may be unreliable


> m0

Coefficients:
       a        b 
1.003692 2.956433 

Log-likelihood: -66.92
```

The results are correct. The maximum likelihood estimates of `a` and `b` respectively are `min(x)` and `max(x)`.

```
> min(x)
[1] 1.003692
> max(x)
[1] 2.956433
```

Comment: Hi @stephane. I am very thankful for your answer. 1 more thing, I am interested in finding the standard error of my estimates a and b. But apparently your code produces "NA" for standard error under summary(m0). Do you have any idea if it's doable?

Comment: @PiyushVerma Sorry I don't know this topic. It's possible that it's not doable because the estimates are at the boundary of the domain. Maybe you could ask on <stats.stackexchange.com>.

Comment: Yes you are correct. How I missed the fact that the 1st derivative of log-likelihood function for uniform distribution is constant and hence there is no such values for a and b which maximizes the log-likelihood function. It should have been obvious. But I am still learning this topic. Anyways thanks for putting effort Stephane. Have a nice day.

Comment: No, there are some values maximizing the likelihood. The likelihood is `1/(b-a)` *for `a<min(x)` and `b>max(x)`*. It is maximal when `b-a` is the smallest possible, that is when `a=min(x)` and `b=max(x)`.